# Fiddler output has unknown prefix and postfix

Tags: output, fiddler, prefix

When i compose a POST request on my web service using Fiddler Web Debugger (v4.5.1.2), the expected output does always have a prefix and postfix.

**In this case: 23b & 0**.

Top screen: (geojson) input, bottom screen: output.

[image]

Anyone an idea why this is and how to get rid of it?
When i generate output in Eclipse, the prefix/postfix are not shown.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the output is encoded (as stated in the infobar :)). Transforming the output to a regular response gets rid of the prefix and postfix!

Not really a solution, more like a clarification.

Top: Click yellow bar to decode, Bottem: result
[image: Top: Click yellow bar to decode, Bottem: result]

Comment: The response used `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, a scheme whereby the content length can be omitted from the headers by sending the response body in size-prefixed "chunks." See the HTTP RFC for more information.